# Redundant LIMIT clause modifies results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm seeing very strange results from postgres. Does anyone know how this can happen? I have a complex query, let's call it A:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (A LIMIT 100000) a;
2230
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (A) a;
2230
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (A LIMIT 100000) a WHERE position_id = 'f9f49009-8f95-4d29-a5e0-c0afaa71d3d3';
0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (A) a WHERE position_id = 'f9f49009-8f95-4d29-a5e0-c0afaa71d3d3';
17
```

There are fewer than 100000 rows so the LIMIT should have no effect. But somehow it does.

Btw, the reason for the LIMIT is that this query comes from a BI tool which automatically inserts a limit. We're seeing the wrong numbers in the BI tool and I've narrowed it down to this.

This is postgres version 10.1

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you create a self-contained testcase, e.g. on sqlfiddle?

Comment: I don't believe you are using standard PostgreSQL v10. Like it should, your first query gives me `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIMIT"` because there is no `SELECT` in the parenthesis.

Comment: Laurentz, this is a simplified example. "A" is actually a full query with a SELECT.

Comment: @maniek, thanks for the response. I've been trying, but can't create a smaller testcase. Even when I create temporary tables with intermediate results, the final query result changes on me. I'm seeing strange behavior like:

`B # ~2200 rows, none of which position_id = 'f9f49009-8f95-4d29-a5e0-c0afaa71d3d3'`
<br/>
`SELECT * FROM (B) a WHERE position_id = 'f9f49009-8f95-4d29-a5e0-c0afaa71d3d3'; # 17 rows`
Simple changes to the query change the results in unexpected ways.

Comment: Btw, there are window functions in there which maybe are causing the strange behavior.